# Selenium in Notebook vs. Script

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

Running into something interesting when trying to set up a Selenium webdriver to scrape fantasy football stats from ESPN. When I execute the following cells in a jupyter notebook I can reach the page I'm looking for (the draft recap page of my fantasy league) and successfully login to my account, accessing the page:

```
# cell 1
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# cell 2
i = 0
iter_again = True

iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
while i < len(iframes) and iter_again:
    driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[i])
    if (len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input-wrapper"))) > 0:
        username, password = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input-wrapper")
    iter_again = False
else:
    sleep(1)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    i += 1

# Cell 3
username.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')[0].send_keys(espn_username)
password.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')[0].send_keys(espn_password)

# Cell 4
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[0].click()

# Cell 5
driver.refresh()
```

The strange thing though is that when I put all of this in a function and return the webdriver object, espn won't let me log in. I get an error message saying that ESPN is experiencing technical difficulties at this time and I may not be able to login (they're right I can't).

I initially thought this could be some sort of rate limiting thing but can't think of anything different in the HTTP request from the functional form vs. the cell-by-cell approach. For what it's worth, I've tested the functional approach in both a jupyter notebook environment as well as running from a standalone script via the CLI. Any thoughts? All help/feedback is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT - Adding the script that doesn't execute properly**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
time import sleep

def get_active_webdriver(url, espn_username, espn_password, headless=False):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    i = 0
    iter_again = True

    # find iframe with the login info and log in
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    while i < len(iframes) and iter_again:
        driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[i])
        if (len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input-wrapper"))) > 0:
            username, password = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input-wrapper")
        iter_again = False
    else:
        sleep(1)
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
        i += 1

    username.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')[0].send_keys(espn_username)
    password.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')[0].send_keys(espn_password)

    driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[0].click()
    driver.refresh()

    return driver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = #url here
    espn_username = #username
    espn_password = #password
    driver = get_active_webdriver(url, espn_username, espn_password)
```

Comment: Can you share the function that doesn't work?

Comment: Just added it - thanks for taking a look!